# How to refer to all IPv6 IP addresses using mask?

Tags: ip, ipv6

I known that I can refer to all IPv4 IP addresses with mask `0.0.0.0/0`.

What is the address that matches all IPv6 IP addresses?

Comment: IP is Internet Protocol, and there are only two current IPs: IPv4 and IPv6. I think you mean IP addresses.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is ::/0, which is short for 0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000/0.

Comment: Thank you! This is the answer I was looking for.